# SharePoint 2013 resize lookup field new/edit item

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-designer

I am trying to resize a lookup field to be wider since the options are too long and get cut off. I have searched for a solution but nothing seems to quite work. My SharePoint skills are less than average (I've been dabbling on the side for a couple months), so I apologize if this is a simple fix.

The fields that need to be resized:
[image]

```
<tr>
    <td width="190px" valign="top" class="ms-formlabel">
        <H3 class="ms-standardheader">
            <nobr>Add to Groups</nobr>
        </H3>
    </td>
    <td width="400px" valign="top" class="ms-formbody">
        <SharePoint:FormField runat="server" id="ff24{$Pos}" ControlMode="New" FieldName="Add_x0020_to_x0020_Domain_x0020_" __designer:bind="{ddwrt:DataBind('i',concat('ff24',$Pos),'Value','ValueChanged','ID',ddwrt:EscapeDelims(string(@ID)),'@Add_x0020_to_x0020_Domain_x0020_')}"/>
        <SharePoint:FieldDescription runat="server" id="ff24description{$Pos}" FieldName="Add_x0020_to_x0020_Domain_x0020_" ControlMode="New"/>
    </td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td width="190px" valign="top" class="ms-formlabel">
        <H3 class="ms-standardheader">
            <nobr>Add to Distro Lists</nobr>
        </H3>
    </td>
    <td width="400px" valign="top" class="ms-formbody">
        <SharePoint:FormField runat="server" id="ff25{$Pos}" ControlMode="New" FieldName="Add_x0020_to_x0020_Distro_x0020_" __designer:bind="{ddwrt:DataBind('i',concat('ff25',$Pos),'Value','ValueChanged','ID',ddwrt:EscapeDelims(string(@ID)),'@Add_x0020_to_x0020_Distro_x0020_')}"/>
        <SharePoint:FieldDescription runat="server" id="ff25description{$Pos}" FieldName="Add_x0020_to_x0020_Distro_x0020_" ControlMode="New"/>
    </td>
</tr>
```

I changed the width for every section but it made no difference to the output. If there is another section of code I need to post I can add it. I'm working in SharePoint Designer 2013.

Answer (score 2):

The tables you refer to have a fixed with in their HTML, which is why applying CSS to them might not seem to work. The cure is to use CSS's `!Important` to override HTML style rules.

To change e.g. both the height and the width of the all tables shown, apply the following change:

```
.ms-formlabel ~ .ms-formbody table.ms-long .ms-input select {
    width: 250px !Important;
    height: 300px !Important;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Another way would be to use the SPServices.js library (http://sympmarc.github.io/SPServices/).

It has a function $().SPServices.SPSetMultiSelectSizes. Give it the display name of the field and a min and max size.

Answer (score 0):

The width (400px) you have specified for TD not going to work for SharePoint select control because they are control level styles.
[image]

To apply the change to the control add the following CSS to the page.

```
<style type="text/css">
select {
    width: 200px !important;
}
</style>
```

Refer the below image to know where you can add that
[image]

Answer (score 0):

Use JQuery to set the css property of the field. You need to set the width of each side separately. This works perfectly in SP 2016 On Prem.

```
var standardWidth = '250px';

//File Type
$("select[title='File Type possible values']").css('width',standardWidth);
$("select[title='File Type selected values']").css('width',standardWidth);

//Category
$("select[title='Category possible values']").css('width',standardWidth);
$("select[title='Category selected values']").css('width',standardWidth);
```